# How do I get this header to being in the center of the page?

Tags: css, html, text-align

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/ReportPanel.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h3>Test Page</h3>
            @* Start Date *@ 
            @* End Date *@
        </header>
        <h3>Test Page</h3>
        <main role="main">
            Hi there
            Hello
            <br />
            <br />
            Meh
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
}

main {
    display:block;
}

h3 {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This seems to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Tks6C/

This will center everything you have in the `header` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

should fix it!

or you can also do

```
header {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[This link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa090407.htm) will help explain more about how nesting HTML tags works

Comment: The margin trick will not center it in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/MA425/

Comment: anytime you do width:100% you need to make sure the containing element (body, in this case) has no padding/margin/border.

Comment: and even if you did do that the width would need to be less than 100% to make any difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to center the whole header rather than just the text inside, you could use something like below.

```
body {
   width: 100%
}

header {
   width: 200px; /* change this width */
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: lol that's not how you do comments in css, bud

Comment: Comments updated, bud.

Comment: you should update them one more time :p look closer

Comment: For your purposes (author) you can remove the css comment. @Adelphia - I can't see anything wrong with it - can you enlighten me?

Comment: What did you edit, @Adelphia?

Comment: He/she changed height to with.

Comment: Hah, wow. Long day. Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
header{
text-align:center;
}
```

is all you need

Comment: The `margin:auto` trick doesn't work with this: http://jsfiddle.net/D7TUw/

Comment: my fault. that wont work unless the element has a set width. since h3 is a block level element it takes up all available width. all he needs is a simple text-align:center on the header..